# table.getn is deprecated - How can I get the length of an array?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to get the length of an array in Lua with `table.getn`. I receive this error:

> The function table.getn is deprecated!

(In Transformice Lua)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `#`:

```
> a = {10, 11, 12, 13}
> print(#a)
4
```

---

Notice however that the length operator `#` does not work with tables that are not arrays, it only counts the number of elements in the array part (with indices 1, 2, 3 etc.).

This won't work:

```
> a = {1, 2, [5] = 7, key = '1234321', 15}
> print(#a)
3
```

Here only (1, 2 and 15) are in the array part.

Comment: Thaaaaanks! :D I guess I will have no problem using this # because I create normal arrays.

Answer (score 14):

For tables that actually have key-value pairs, you can write a simple function that counts them:

```
function getTableSize(t)
    local count = 0
    for _, __ in pairs(t) do
        count = count + 1
    end
    return count
end
```